# Error Tomcat when deploy project war

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, automated-tests, tomcat6, spring-webflow

I have a problem when I deployed file war in tomcat6 on my Server CentOS.

I used

- CentOS 5.x
- Tomcat version6
- Java version ( I use javasun )

> ```
> java version "1.6.0_30"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
> ```

Here is a Error when Tomcat started to deploy

```
2012-01-05 17:19:27,763 DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement] {pstm-100001} Parameters: [10000, 0]
2012-01-05 17:19:27,763 DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement] {pstm-100001} Parameters: [10000, 0]
2012-01-05 17:19:27,764 DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement] {pstm-100001} Types: [java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer]
2012-01-05 17:19:27,764 DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement] {pstm-100001} Types: [java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer]
2012-01-05 17:19:27,766 DEBUG [java.sql.ResultSet] {rset-100002} ResultSet
2012-01-05 17:19:27,766 DEBUG [java.sql.ResultSet] {rset-100002} ResultSet
2012-01-05 17:19:27,831 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'backupScheduler' defined in file [/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/egovframework-all-in-one-2.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/egovframework/spring/com/context-scheduling-sym-sym-bak.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
```

Here is file context-scheduling-sym-sym-bak.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">`

    <bean id="egovBackupOpertService" class="egovframework.com.sym.sym.bak.service.impl.EgovBackupOpertServiceImpl" />

    <!-- 백업관리 스케줄러 -->
    <bean id="backupScheduler" class="egovframework.com.sym.sym.bak.service.BackupScheduler"
        init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="egovBackupOpertService" ref="egovBackupOpertService"/>
        <property name="idgenService" ref="egovBackupResultIdGnrService"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Please Help me everyone, Thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to have some error in your Query. .  !! The Prepared Statement itself is showing that. Is your query executing on your database?

Answer (score 0):

According to your stacktrace, it looks like you have a NullPointerException in your init() method of the egovframework.com.sym.sym.bak.service.BackupScheduler class.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew stated, your stacktrace is showing that the initialization of the backupScheduler bean is running into a null pointer.

From looking at your .xml file your backupScheduler bean contains a reference to a bean called "egovBackupResultIdGnrService"

```
<bean id="backupScheduler" class="egovframework.com.sym.sym.bak.service.BackupScheduler"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="egovBackupOpertService" ref="egovBackupOpertService"/>

    <-- THIS BEAN RIGHT HERE -->
    <property name="idgenService" ref="egovBackupResultIdGnrService"/>
</bean>
```

but I don't see this bean being declared anywhere in this .xml file. Is this bean declared somewhere else?

Comment: Hi everyone, this project I have deployed in other server, it was working. but on that above server it was not working. About <property name="idgenService" ref="egovBackupResultIdGnrService"/> egovBackupResultIdGnrService, I have declared in other file xml ready. I think root cause of problem from JVM. i'm not sure. Do you have any idea ?